# In pandas dataframe keep repeated values that are only in a group, if value is repeated after other value then print some message

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

Example Dataframe:

```
A1
A1
A1 #these values are ok because these are repeated continuously
A2
A3
A4
A1 #this is duplicate value as this is not in continuation
A5
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
#test if duplciated, first dupe is False
df['dup'] = df['col'].duplicated()
#consecutive groups
df['g'] = df['col'].ne(df['col'].shift()).cumsum()
#test if not all Trues per groups
df['new'] = ~df.groupby('g')['dup'].transform('all')
print (df)
  col    dup  g    new
0  A1  False  1   True
1  A1   True  1   True
2  A1   True  1   True
3  A2  False  2   True
4  A2   True  2   True
5  A3  False  3   True
6  A4  False  4   True
7  A1   True  5  False
8  A5  False  6   True
```

If need test only alone repeated values:

```
print (df)
   col
0   A1
1   A1
2   A1
3   A2
4   A2
5   A3
6   A4
7   A1
8   A1
9   A5
10  A1
```

---

```
#same like first solution
df['dup'] = df['col'].duplicated()
df['g'] = df['col'].ne(df['col'].shift()).cumsum()
df['rem1'] = ~df.groupby('g')['dup'].transform('all')
#test if all dupes by groups g
df['rem2']  = df['g'].duplicated(keep=False)
#chain by | for bitwise OR
df['new']  = df['rem1'] | df['rem2']
print (df)
   col    dup  g   rem1   rem2    new
0   A1  False  1   True   True   True
1   A1   True  1   True   True   True
2   A1   True  1   True   True   True
3   A2  False  2   True   True   True
4   A2   True  2   True   True   True
5   A3  False  3   True  False   True
6   A4  False  4   True  False   True
7   A1   True  5  False   True   True
8   A1   True  5  False   True   True
9   A5  False  6   True  False   True
10  A1   True  7  False  False  False
```